# Strange Qt Creator behavior when using std::thread

Tags: qt-creator, stdthread

While playing with C++ 11's `std::thread`, I found the following strange application behavior (using Qt Creator 2.7.2):

File main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        j = 0;
    }

    void run() {
        std::thread t(&A::foo, this, 4, 5);
        t.join();
    }

private:
    int j;

    void foo(int x, int y) {
        j+=x; j+=y;
        std::cout << "foo: " << x << " " << y << " " << j << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED(argc);
    Q_UNUSED(argv);

    A a;
    a.run();
    a.run();
    a.run();

    return 0;
}
```

.pro file:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Threads
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -pthread

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

When running it with 'Run in terminal disabled', the output produced is either:

> foo: 4 5 9
>   foo: 4 5 18
>   foo: 4 5 27

(expected)

or:

> foo: 4 5 9
>   foo: 4 5 18

(wrong, one run() call missing)

Since this application is not really multi-threaded yet (only one child thread running always), it does not look like a race condition. Any idea what is wrong in the attached code?